# haskell print 10 times input string, do-notation

Tags: string, haskell, monads

Take input as a string and print it 10 times using do-notation?

```haskell
print10Times :: String -> IO ()
print10Times name = putStrLn $ repeat 10 name

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "What is your name?"
  name <- getLine
  print10Times name
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `replicateM_` for this.

```
Λ: :t replicateM_
replicateM_ :: Monad m => Int -> m a -> m ()
Λ: do { putStrLn "what is your name?" ; name <- getLine ; replicateM_ 10 (putStrLn name) }
what is your name?
none of your business
none of your business
none of your business
none of your business
none of your business
none of your business
none of your business
none of your business
none of your business
none of your business
none of your business
```

Comment: with `:set +m` you can enable multi line input mode in ghci.

Answer (score 4):

`repeat` only takes a single argument and repeats it indefinitely. You are probably looking for `take 10 $ repeat name`.

If you want to print a list, you may be better off using `mapM_` to map `putStrLn` against each element in the list. Try this out:

```haskell
print10Times :: String -> IO ()
print10Times name = mapM_ putStrLn $ take 10 $ repeat name
```

Or, put more succinctly:

```haskell
print10Times = mapM_ putStrLn . take 10 . repeat
```

Comment: `replicate 10` is a better version of `take 10 . repeat`.

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely use `replicateM_` like [@pdexter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37682359/67579) suggests, or you can rewrite it using recursion:

```
print10Times :: String -> IO ()
print10Times = printNTimes 10

printNTimes :: Int -> String -> IO ()
printNTimes n name | n <= 0 = return ()
                   | otherwise = do
                         putStrLn name
                         printNTimes (n-1) name

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "What is your name?"
  name <- getLine
  print10Times name
```

`print10Times` simply redirects control to `printNTimes` with a constant `10` (the number of times it should be printed). Then a decrement is performed each time the name is printed and `return ()` is done if the counter hits `0`.

This is a bit reinventing `replicateM_` which could be defined as:

```
replicateM_ :: (Monad m, Num n, Ord n) => n -> m a -> m ()
replicateM_ n f = loop n
    where loop i | i <= 0 = return ()
                 | otherwise = f >> loop (i-1)
```